# NO OUTPUT WHILE CONVERTING TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'MONTH')

Tags: sql, oracle

Why does the first query returns no rows when I search employees hired in May or November but the second one does? my default date format is rr-mm-dd .
Also is there a way to search if I don't know the default date format?

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,LAST_NAME||', '||FIRST_NAME"Full Name",JOB_ID,HIRE_DATE
 FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE UPPER(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'MONTH')) IN ('MAY','NOVEMBER');


SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,LAST_NAME||', '||FIRST_NAME"Full Name",JOB_ID,HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'MM') IN ('11','05');
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Comment: Oracle users can only talk in CAPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has several issues.

When you use `TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'MONTH')` then month name is padded with space characters, try `TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'"MONTH"')` to see the effect. It should return `"MAY      "`

Another issue is the current user session `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` which determines the language of month names.

If you insist to use the month names then use

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'fmMONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') IN ('MAY','NOVEMBER')
```

or

```
WHERE TRIM(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')) IN ('MAY','NOVEMBER')
```

However, the best way would be not using the names but month numbers. Instead of `TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'MM')` you could also use `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIRE_DATE)` which returns the month as number.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `TO_CHAR` is that it won't trim trailing whitespaces.

You should use

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,LAST_NAME||', '||FIRST_NAME"Full Name",JOB_ID,HIRE_DATE
 FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE TRIM(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'MONTH') IN ('MAY','NOVEMBER');
```

You also don't need `UPPER` if you are already using capital `MONTH` in `to_char`.